How can i read a web.config as well as a local.settings.json file in a .Net app using c#?
I have a .net app and azure function apps that access a routine in the .net app. Now this routine is used for logging some information.
Within the .net app i can access the web.config file as follows
     var serviceSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("servicename");

etc and get the values from the web.config.
But when an Azure function ap calls it there is no such thing as a web.config but a local.setting.json file for development .
What is the json file called when it is deployed ?
How can i read the Azure function app config file in the .net app ?
So basicallly i want to be able to know if an Azaure function app is calling the .net function and read the value or if its withing the app itself just read the web.config file ?

For a deployed azure functions app it's common practice to store config data in environment variables directly in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=azure-portal%2Cto-premium If you just want to know who called a .net function why dont you pass an additional parameter "caller" which you fill with "azure-function" during your function call?

not exactly what i am after . I have a .net app and i want to read the web.config value if the value is null , then i want to read the read the json file . How can i do that all in a .net app ?
